# python: urlParse fault? parser Python 3

Tags: javascript, python

I have the following code(gdaten[n][2] gives an URL, n is the index):

```
    try:
        p=urlparse(gdaten[n][2])
        while p.scheme == "javascript" or p.scheme == "mailto":
            p=urlparse(gdaten[n][2])
            print(p," was skipped (", gdaten[n][2],")")
            n += 1
        print ("check:", gdaten[n][2])
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(gdaten[n][2])
        htmlcode = str(f.read())
        parser = MyHTMLParser(strict=False)
        parser.feed(htmlcode)

    except urllib.error.URLError:
        #do some stuff
    except IndexError:
        #do some stuff
    except ValueError:
        #do some stuff
```

Now I have the following error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: javascript>
```

in line 8. How is that possible? I thought with the while-loop I skip all those links with the scheme javascript? Why does the except not work? Where's my fault?
`MyHTMLParser`appends the links found on the website to gdaten like that `[[stuff,stuff, link][stuff,stuff, link]`

Comment: That is not the real indentation of your code right? Also, can you show us a little more of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is an off by one error.

In other words, `n` and `p` are out of sync.

To fix this, add one to `n` before setting `p`.

## Why wasn't this working?

Assuming `n` is set to zero at the start (could start at `42`, it doesn't matter), let's say gdaten is laid out like so:

```
gdaten[0][2] = "javascript://blah.js"
gdaten[1][2] = "http://hello.com"
gdaten[2][2] = "javascript://moo.js"
```

Upon checking the first while condition, p.scheme is `'javascript'` so we enter the loop. `p` gets set to `urlparse("javascript://blah.js")` again and `n` is increased to 1. Since we're checking `urlparse("javascript://blah.js")` again, we continue into the loop again.

`p` now gets set to `urlparse("http://hello.com")` and `n` gets set to `2`.

Since `urlparse("http://hello.com")` passes the check, the while loop ends.

Meanwhile, since `n` is two, the url that gets opened is `gdaten[2][2]` which is `"javascript://moo.js"`

## Code fix

```
try:
    p=urlparse(gdaten[n][2])
    while p.scheme == "javascript" and p.scheme == "mailto" and not p.scheme:
        print(p," was skipped (", gdaten[n][2],")")

        # Skipping to the next value
        n += 1
        p=urlparse(gdaten[n][2])

    print ("check:", gdaten[n][2])
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(gdaten[n][2])
    htmlcode = str(f.read())

...
```

Comment: Tried exactly that 10 secs before you answered